# Javascript not recognizing space in string as a character

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making a typewriter effect from an array of strings, some of which have spaces in them. In strings with spaces, the cursor pauses on the last letter of each word and then skips to the first letter of the next word, instead of advancing with the space. The character counter, however, advances as expected on the spaces.

How can I fix this? I assume I need to do something with

```
&nbsp;
```

but I've tried everything I can think of.

The cursor is just a right border on a blank div:

```js
var words = ["fun", "exciting", "about not giving up", "being helpful", "being open"],
  el = document.getElementById('magic'),
  word_counter = 0,
  character_counter = 0;

function updateText() {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + words[word_counter][character_counter++];
  if (character_counter == words[word_counter].length + 1) {
    word_counter++;
    character_counter = 0;
    el.innerHTML = '';
    if (word_counter == words.length) {
      word_counter = 0;
    }
  }
}

setInterval(updateText, 100);
```

```css
#magic {
  color: #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  padding-right: 7px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="magic"></div>
```

Comment: Take a look at CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var words = ["fun", "exciting", "about not giving up", "being helpful", "being open"],
    el = document.getElementById('magic'),
    word_counter = 0,
    character_counter = 0;

function updateText()
{
    var nextChar = words[word_counter][character_counter++];
    if(nextChar == " ") {nextChar = "&nbsp;";}
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML+ nextChar;
    if(character_counter == words[word_counter].length+1)
    {
        word_counter++;     
        character_counter = 0;  
        el.innerHTML = '';  
        if(word_counter == words.length) {
            word_counter = 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! The problem is not with javascript but with HTML. HTML does not print trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Slowing down the interval, I was able to see your issue and the problem what you were describing, as I understand it.

The issue is with outputting a space as you guessed, but it's only a perceptive issue.  Because it's a space, our eyes don't notice much a change, so it appears as though the cursor is hanging.  In reality, the sequence is: output character,  pause, output space, pause, output next character.

For this there are two simple solutions:

## 1. Change White-space Setting

If you want your cursor to move on a space, simply add one line to your `#magic` CSS: `white-space:pre-wrap;`

```js
var words = ["fun", "exciting", "about not giving up", "super-spaces…                                                 …done","being helpful", "being open"],
  el = document.getElementById('magic'),
  word_counter = 0,
  character_counter = 0;

function updateText() {
  
  var new_character = words[word_counter][character_counter++];
  el.innerHTML += new_character;
  
  if (character_counter == words[word_counter].length + 1) {
    word_counter++;
    character_counter = 0;
    el.innerHTML = '';
    if (word_counter == words.length) {
      word_counter = 0;
    }
  }
}

setInterval(updateText, 100);
```

```css
#magic {
  color: #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  padding-right: 7px;
  display: inline;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="magic"></div>
```

## 2. When Space, Output Again

If you do not care about the cursor moving with the space and only want to remove the pause, one method is to check the outputted character and if it's a space character, just call the function again to output the next character:

```js
var words = ["fun", "exciting", "about not giving up", "super-spaces…                                                 …done", "being helpful", "being open"],
  el = document.getElementById('magic'),
  word_counter = 0,
  character_counter = 0;

function updateText() {
  
  var new_character = words[word_counter][character_counter++];
  el.textContent += new_character;
  
  if (character_counter == words[word_counter].length + 1) {
    word_counter++;
    character_counter = 0;
    el.innerHTML = '';
    if (word_counter == words.length) {
      word_counter = 0;
    }
  }
  
  //  Test for whitespace characters
  if (/\s/.test(new_character)) {
    updateText();
    return;
  }

}

setInterval(updateText, 100);
```

```css
#magic {
  color: #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  padding-right: 7px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="magic"></div>
```

Comment: @Krista see here

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the char is a space, if so, you have to add `&nbsp` instead of the space

```
function updateText(){
    var char = words[word_counter][character_counter++];
    if (char == " "){
        char = "&nbsp;";
    }
    el.innerHTML += char;
    if(character_counter == words[word_counter].length+1)
    {
        word_counter++;     
        character_counter = 0;  
        el.innerHTML = '';  
        if(word_counter == words.length) {
            word_counter = 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you doing something like this?

```js
var words = ["fun", "exciting", "about not giving up", "being helpful", "being open"],
        el = document.getElementById('magic'),
        word_counter = 0,
        character_counter = 0;

    function updateText()
    {
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML+words[word_counter][character_counter++];
        if(character_counter == words[word_counter].length)
        {
            word_counter=(word_counter+1)%words.length;     
            character_counter = 0;  
            
            el.innerHTML=!word_counter?'':el.innerHTML+ ' ';  
        }
    }
    
setInterval(updateText,100);
```

```css
#magic{
    color: #777;
    border-right: 1px solid #777;
    padding-right: 7px;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="magic"></div>
```